# How can I access files in a particular directory in my flutter app

Tags: image, file, flutter, dart, storage

so I want to access files in a particular directory on my device but i do not know how to
In particular I just want the app to go into the devices internal storage and get some files from some particular locations

[image: So this is the devices list of files]

In this list of files i want to access the other documents inside the XENDER directory

[image]

And in the XENDER directory I now want to access the files in the IMAGES document

[image]

Now over here Just want to be able to list the images in my flutter app in a listview and when any of them is clicked i can get the image saved in a file

like this

```
File file = await asset.file;
```

so i can use it in other places in the app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should check out the path provider plugin on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider). What you want to do is read the Xender/image directory and say map them to a list or something. See my implementation below. I am trying to show the images in a staggered view(assuming the images are in jpg format): First, add the path provider plugin to your pubspec.yaml

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

final Directory _photoDir = Directory('/storage/emulated/0/Xender/image');

class Photos extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PhotosState createState() {
    return new PhotosState();
  }
}

class PhotosState extends State {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if(!Directory("${_photoDir.path}").existsSync()) {
      return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Xender Images"),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
          child: Center(
            child: Text("All Xender images should appear here", style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 18.0
            ),),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }else {
      var imageList = _photoDir.listSync().map((item) => item.path).where((
          item) => item.endsWith(".jpg")).toList(growable: false);

      if (imageList.length > 0) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Xender Images"),
          ),
          body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
            child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemCount: imageList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                String imgPath = imageList[index];
                return Material(
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                  child: InkWell(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Hero(
                      tag: imgPath,
                      child: Image.file(
                        File(imgPath),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (i) =>
                  StaggeredTile.count(2, i.isEven ? 2 : 3),
              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            ),
          ),
         );
      } else {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Xender images"),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60.0),
              child: Text("Sorry, No Images Where Found.", style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0
              ),),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, am yet to try it, I will now but can I please ask what exactly the storage/emulated/0 means? is every devices storage arranged like that

Comment: storage/emulated/0 is the device root directory or what you would call the phone local storage.

Comment: `storage/emulated/0` it is possible in ios?